# Can I make an xbar plot based on an external file?

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to use the, imho, most common value alignment of x- and y-values in an external file and then produce an `xbar` with it. It shall look like the examples [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52767/25683) (the better example because there are two values for each `ytick`) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96392/25683). Is that possible?

I'd rather not enter the data for the coordinates myself.

The MWE is based upon [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31701/25683) and does not work.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
    lmodern,
    amsmath
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
    pgfplots
    }

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Subjects;Min;Max
Test01;0.5;7
Test02;-2;4
Test03;-1;6
Test04;0;3
Test05;2;4
Test06;1;7
\end{filecontents}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
Test.
\begin{center}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%
xbar,
xlabel={aaaa values},
ylabel={Subjects},
ytick=data,
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
%yticklabels from table={data.csv}{Subjects},
%symbolic y coords={Test01,Test02,Test03,Test04,Test05,Test06}
]
\addplot table [x index=1, y index=0, col sep=semicolon] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

### MWE 2 for aligning bars & labels

This MWE is there to show that the alignment of the x-labels and bars is off.

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
    lmodern,
    amsmath
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
    pgfplots
    }

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Subjects;Min;Max
Test01;0.5;7
Test02;-2;4
Test03;-1;6
Test04;0;3
Test05;2;4
Test06;1;7
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{
Subjects;Min;Max
Test01;0.5;7
Test02;-2;4
Test03;-1;6
Test04;0;3
Test05;2;4
Test06;1;7
}\tableabcdef

\begin{document}
Test.
\begin{center}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar,
xlabel={aaaa values},
xmin=0,
%ytick=data,
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
yticklabels from table={\tableabcdef}{Subjects},
]
%\addplot table [meta=Subjects, x=Min] {\tableabcdef};
\addplot table [meta=Subjects, x=Max] {\tableabcdef};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

### Picture for MWE 2

[image]

Comment: Add `y expr=\coordindex` to the `\addplot table [...]` options (and load the `pgfplotstable` package)

Comment: @Jake It works! Note: I had to comment in `ytick=data` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods are utilized. The first method uses `\pgfplotstableread` which needs `pgfplotstable`, the second method uses `filecontents` environment

**Update:** About the same time as the first proposal was out, the OP updated a different sets of data and incorporated Jake's suggestions. Here is the updated output.

[image]

**Updated Code**

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
    lmodern,
    amsmath
}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
    pgfplots
    }

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Subjects;Min;Max
Test01;0.5;7
Test02;-2;4
Test03;-1;6
Test04;0;3
Test05;2;4
Test06;1;7
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{
Subjects;Min;Max
Test01;0.5;7
Test02;-2;4
Test03;-1;6
Test04;0;3
Test05;2;4
Test06;1;7
}\tableabcdef

\begin{document}
Test.
\begin{center}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar,
xlabel={aaaa values},
xmin=-4,
ytick=data,
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
yticklabels from table={\tableabcdef}{Subjects},
]
%\addplot table [meta=Subjects, x=Min] {\tableabcdef};
\foreach \i in {Min,Max}{
\addplot table [meta=Subjects, y expr=\coordindex, x=\i] {\tableabcdef};}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
    lmodern,
    amsmath
}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
    pgfplots
    }


\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Subjects,Min,Max
TestA,0.5,7
TestB,-2,4
WordA,-1,6
WordB,0,3
NameA,5,4
NameB,1,7
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Subjects,Min,Max
TestA,0.5,7
TestB,-2,4
WordA,-1,6
WordB,0,3
NameA,5,4
NameB,1,7
}\datatable

%\listfiles

\begin{document}
Test.
\begin{center}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xbar, 
xlabel={aaaa values},
ytick=data,
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Subjects}
]
\addplot table [meta=Subjects, x=Min] {\datatable};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%

\begin{center}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xbar,
xlabel={aaaa values},
ytick=data,
yticklabels = {TestA,TestB,WordA,WordB,NameA,NameB},
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
%yticklabels from table={data.csv}{index=0}
]
\addplot table [meta index =0, x index =1, col sep = comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I updated my MWE in the meantime but I can follows your code of course. Is it possible to display both values (min and max) for a subject? Also, the y-labels are aligned by their x values which is quite irritating. I am looking for a solution there myself but maybe someone else knows better already.

Comment: You can change `xbar` to `xbar stacked` and add one more line `\addplot table [meta=Subjects, x=Max] {\datatable};`

Comment: Oh, right. Didn't see the forest for the trees here.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't fully work out the way I intend it to do. I added a second MWE with picture at the bottom of the op.

Comment: enable the `ytick=data`. It was marked out.

Comment: And Jake provided the other relevant tidbit: **1.** loading `pgfplotstable` **2.** adding `y expr=\coordindex` as an option to the `\addplot` line. So I'll mark your post then. If you could edit those details in, it would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: @henry -- added Jake's suggestion.

Comment: Note that instead of using `\pgfplotstableread` you can instead use the key `table/col sep=comma`, h/t https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578296/2066