# How do I decrease vertical spacing in xbar stacked pgfplots charts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, vertical-spacing

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
name,a,b
name1,1000,1000000
name2,1000,1000000
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{test.csv}\datatable
  \begin{axis}[
      xbar stacked,   % Stacked horizontal bars
      ytick=data,     % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
      yticklabels from table={\datatable}{name},
      scaled x ticks=false,
    ]
    \addplot table [x=a,  meta=name, col sep=comma, y expr=\coordindex] {test.csv};
    \addplot table [x=b,  meta=name, col sep=comma, y expr=\coordindex] {test.csv};
    \legend{a,b}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get
[image]

I want something like

[image]

How do I get pgf to generate this plot (rather than having to do it in paint?)

Comment: I would have legend out of diagram. To my opinion the xtick labels would be better readable if you move `10^5`  to `xlabel` (now not present in diagram) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adjusting the `axis`' `height`. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
name,a,b
name1,1000,1000000
name2,1000,1000000
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % adjust the `height` and keep the `width`
        width=\axisdefaultwidth,
        height=3cm,
        % in addition something like this is needed so the bars don't
        % extend the axis limits and thus get cropped
        enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
        % ---
        xbar stacked,
        ytick=data,
        % (you can state the file name here as well)
        yticklabels from table={test.csv}{name},
        scaled x ticks=false,
        % (this sets all labels to the same base
        %  compare the first two x labels (0 and 2*10^5) with your image)
        typeset ticklabels with strut,
        % (moved common stuff here so you don't need to repeat it)
        table/col sep=comma,
        table/y expr=\coordindex,
        table/meta=name,
    ]
        \addplot table [x=a] {test.csv};
        \addplot table [x=b] {test.csv};
        \legend{a,b}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks!  You claim "% (you can state the file name here as well)" but when I do that in my actual example, I get the error "! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'Project' from table 'proof-overhead-no-fiat-crypto.csv'. Please check spelling (or introduce name aliases)..", I think because it's trying to read the file as something other than comma-separated?    In any case, this fixes my problem

Comment: Oh, I see, I was missing the `table/col sep=comma` key